# how to download zip-file from client machine instead of opening file in browser using java?

Tags: java, servlets, download, zip

the given below code for downloading file to client machine. I am trying to download file to client machine using java servlet. but it's not downloaded i checked in console but no error occur

try {

```
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadPath);
                response.setContentType("application/zip");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+dndfilename);
                response.setContentLength(fileInputStream.available());
                int i;
                while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
                    response.getOutputStream().write(i);
//                  System.out.println("Result: " +i);
                }
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
                response.getOutputStream().close();
                fileInputStream.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: This code downloads *to* the client machine. Getting a file *from* a client is called *uploading.* Please clarify which it is you're trying to do. NB You don't have to set the content-length, and using `available()` isn't a valid way to do it.

Comment: @EJP Actually im trying to do download file from server to client & instead of download file open in browser

Comment: Well this should work, as long as it really is a zip file. Get rid of the content-length line.

Comment: @EJP yeah its zip file only

Comment: @EJP Im trying same code in sample project it's work. but i'm integrate to main project it's not working. what's the reason?

Comment: 'Not working' doesn't convey any useful information.

Comment: @EJP now its working i found problem

Comment: @javasundaram either post a solution (as an answer) if you want or close / delete the question. In its current form the question is useless for other SO inhabitants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Actually i send the request in ajax so only it's not working after that i change the request.




 var serverURL = hURL + "/rup";
            var parameters = "requestType=port&subRequestType=portScen&userName=" + userName + "&scen=" + selectedScen;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: parameters,
                url: serverURL,
                cache:false,
                dataType:"html",
                success: function() {
                    updateStatusMessage("success", "Scen port successfully");
                },
                async:false
            });

Solution of the problem:

var serverURL = hURL + "/rpp?requestType=port&subRequestType=portScen&userName=" + userName + "&scen=" + selectedScen;
window.open(serverURL, '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

use out.write and pass file in byte Stream to out.write. It will save file rather opening